# Is it possible to define a 'before_save' callback in a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to define a `before_save` callback in a module? Such that with a class like this:

```
class Model
  include MongoMapper::Document
  include MyModule
end
```

and a module like this:

```
module MyModule
  before_save :do_something

  def do_something
    #do whatever
  end  
end
```

`do_something` will be called before any `Model` objects are saved? I've tried it like this but get `undefined method 'before_save' for MyModule:Module`.

Apologies if it's something simple - I'm new to Ruby and to Rails.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

In Ruby on Rails < 3 (without Rails features, only Ruby)

```
module MyModule
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      before_save :do_something
    end
  end

  def do_something
    #do whatever
  end
end
```

In Ruby on Rails >= 3 (with Rails `Concern` feature)

```
module MyModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save :do_something
  end

  def do_something
    #do whatever
  end
end
```

Comment: Will the approach for Rails < 3 not work in Rails >= 3? I'm doing that and my `before_validation` callback doesn't appear to be called.

Comment: This is correct, but FYI, I just had a module like this which was actually named `Callbacks`, as in `SomeClass::Callbacks`, and it would *not* load. After trying all kinds of stuff, I just renamed it, and it worked. So... beware naming modules "Callbacks" within Rails? I'm using Rails 3.2.8.

Comment: You are my saviour and my sunshine. Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain what `included do` is doing?

Comment: For Rails >= 5. You cannot use [conditional callback](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks)

Answer (score 4):

A module's `included` method might be what you need.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html#method-i-included

Comment: This answer points in a very useful direction, but could use a brief code example and/or discussion of using the `included` method in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with ActiveSupport::Concern(actually and without it, but it more clear and preferred)

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module MyModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # relations, callbacks, validations, scopes and others...
  end

  # instance methods

  module ClassMethods
    # class methods
  end
end
```