# ActiveRecord on create, update of any model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Without STI (Single Table Inheritance), is there a way to check if any model has been created or updated and determine which model and which attributes were changed/updated on the model?

i.e. the output of running a rails server shows all the HTTP traffic and queries being run on the DB.  For cache invalidation purposes, I'm trying to write some code that requires me to know this.

I'm looking for after_create and after_update, but rather than on any one model, I need to have a universal after create and after update and have the ability to determine which model was created or updated.

Can this be done in ActiveRecord?  If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not changing the logic of all models, it isn't a universal hook, so you wouldn't want to do this in `ActiveRecord::Base`.  Duck typing like that is bad.

It sounds like you have common behavior and the way to handle that would be a module (or an `ActiveSupport::Concern`).

Example modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7444654/2483138) (assuming you're running Rails 3+)

```
module MaintainAnInvariant
  # common logic goes here
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_save :maintain_invariant_i_care_about
  end

  def maintain_invariant_i_care_about
    do_stuff_pending_various_logic
  end
end
```

Now each class that shares this logic will explicitly include it, adding semantic value

```
class OneOfTheModelsWithThisLogic < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MaintainAnInvariant
end

class AnotherModelWithCommonLogic < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MaintainAnInvariant
end
```

As for the rest of your answer, how to know what's changed, you're looking for the [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) methods.  These allow you to check what is changed in your models:

```
person.name = 'Bill'
person.name_changed? # => false
person.name_change   # => nil
person.name = 'Bob'
person.changed # => ["name"]
person.changes # => {"name" => ["Bill", "Bob"]}
```

Comment: You're including the code in the model files themselves, so it'll be "that" model, where "that" is whatever model is updating.  I updated my example to make it clear that your `include` code goes in a ActiveRecord model

Comment: How do I know the model in the `maintain_invariant_i_care_about` method?

Comment: the object calling `maintain_invariant_i_care_about` is `self`, but why does it matter?  If it's logic common to any model which includes this module, what's the dependence on the model class?