# Replacing default id for rails with a custom id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, devise-invitable

```
Rails 5.1
Devise
Devise Invitable
```

In models/concerns/shared.rb, I have:

```
module Shared

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def generate_model_id
    self.id = "#{self.class.name}.#{Time.now.to_f.to_s}" if id.blank?
  end
```

In my create_usres migration file, I have:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :users, id: false  do |t|
      t.column :id, :primary_string
```

In my models/user.rb, I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  include Shared

  enum role: [:user, :vip, :admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

In my seeds.rb file, I have:

```
user = User.new(
    :email =>'myemail@mydomain.com',
    :password =>'xK#986754',
    :password_confirmation =>'xK#986754',
    :first_name =>'John',
    :last_name =>'Doe',
    :role => 1,
    :approved => true
)
user.skip_invitation
user.save
```

I have exported all the Devise models (confirmations, invitations, passwords, registrations, sessions, unlocks), and put the corresponding controllers under the controllers/users folder.

Which controller do I call the generate_model_id method from, and where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this you can do in the module that you have created - shared.rb by using active record callbacks.

```
module Shared
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save :generate_model_id
  end

  def generate_model_id
   self.id = "#{self.class.name}.#{Time.now.to_f.to_s}" if id.blank?
  end
end
```

read more about active support callbacks [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html).

Related SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444522/is-it-possible-to-define-a-before-save-callback-in-a-module) thanks.

Comment: this would be one way to go, but it means that it will get called on every cretate/update, when it's only necessary on create

Comment: In such case you can use before_create callback right?